# How to get the properties of the extended parent class to its nested child class?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class A(C):
    def __init__(self, driver):
        super().__init__(driver)

    class B:
        def __init__(self, *args, n=3):
            self.somethingA = args[0]
            self.somethingB = args[1]
```

I need to inherit the property `self.driver` from `Class A` instance extended from `Class C` to the `Class B`.

What I tried:

```
class A(C):
    def __init__(self, driver):
        super().__init__(driver)

    class B:
        def __init__(self, *args, n=3):
            self.somethingA = args[0]
            self.somethingB = args[1]
            self.driver = A.driver
```

But this is faulty. Is there any approach where I can come over this?
Solution for: `A.B(arg0, arg1)`

Comment: `B` is not a child of `A`. Based your indentation, it's not clear whether it is being defined inside `A.__init__` or just inside the class `A` as a nested class.

Comment: `A` doens't have an attribute `driver`; only *instances* of `A` do, which means you'll have to pass an instance of `A` to `B.__init__`. Note that nested class definitions are rare in Python.

Comment: @chepner ohk; may I have that snippet to pass the instance of `A` to `B.__init__`

Comment: @Prashanth `A.B(arg0, arg1, A(driver))`. Though that said, there might be a better way to do it, but it depends what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @wjandrea thanks for this workaround; and yea that works but I want the other way; much more simplified :)

Comment: @Prashanth What do you mean by "other way"?

Comment: @wjandrea here, I am looking for a solution to reach this `A.B(arg0, arg1)`

Answer (score 1):

What the "right" way to approach it will largely depend on what the driver object is. One way to do it is you could make "driver" a class variable to A and then just set it as you need to. The below would set it at init, but if you need it updated then you could have a update method too (would want to fall down to C as well, probably, but I don't know your context).

```
class C(object):
    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.driver = driver

class A(C):
    driver = None
    
    def _set_driver_at_init(self, driver_at_init):
        driver = driver_at_init

    def __init__(self, driver):
        super().__init__(driver)
        self._set_driver_at_init(driver)

    class B:
        def __init__(self, *args, n=3):
            self.somethingA = args[0]
            self.somethingB = args[1]
            self.driver = A.driver
```

Comment: Thank you @andrew; I will try this. Btw I have similar question here, which I am looking for some alternate suggestions to handle it
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62759477/how-to-inherit-the-instance-of-class-a-from-class-c-to-class-b